# Selenium in Excel VBA "findelementbyclass" not working

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a translation code. I can get targeted with xpath but I want to get the data with the class method.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Mydoc As New Selenium.WebDriver
Dim TX As String
Dim i As Integer


dolu = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:A250"))
Mydoc.Start "chrome"
For i = 1 To dolu Step 1
 
TX = Range("A" & i).Value
x1 = "/" & TX


On Error Resume Next


Mydoc.Get "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-turkish" & x1
 xs = ""
 xt = ""
 xu = ""
 
 ''------------------------
 
Set xs = Mydoc.FindElementByClass("def-head ddef_h")
Set xt = Mydoc.FindElementByCss(".def-head ddef_h")



 
''Set xs = Mydoc.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]")
''Set xt = Mydoc.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/span")
''Set xu = Mydoc.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/span")

xs = xs.Text
xt = xt.Text
xu = xu.Text

Range("B" & i).Value = xs
Range("C" & i).Value = xt
Range("D" & i).Value = xu


Next
 

End Sub
```

Comment: What isn't working with your code? Also, you would need FindElementsByClass in order to return a collection you index into in a loop

Comment: The code "1" works, but the code "2" that I want to perform the same function does not work.   1= Set xs = Mydoc.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]") 2=Set xs = Mydoc.FindElementByClass("def-head ddef_h")

Answer (score 0):

Compound (multi-valued) class attributes in css need to be joined with a "." i.e.

```
".def-head.ddef_h"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. now ı have one more problem.        Set xs = Mydoc.FindElementByClass("def-head ddef_h")                this code same code the css, css working but byclass not working. do you have any idea about this.

Comment: Have you input class exactly as appears on page with space?

Comment: Set xs = Mydoc.FindElementByClass("def-head ddef_h") 
yes like that. All the examples I have covered used this way.

Comment: Set xs = Mydoc.FindElementsByClass("def-head ddef_h") .item(1)